# Column Space from Least Sqaures

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, least-squares

Let's say

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
2 & 3  \\
2 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

and $A \cdot x = b$

and
$
b = \begin{bmatrix}
4\\
-1  \\
-1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

After calculating $x = (A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb$, we get 
$x = \begin{bmatrix}
0  \\
0\\
\end{bmatrix}$

So what does it say about $x$ and $b$?

I think the answer is $b$ is not the column space of $A$ because we cannot find any solution of $X$ to equal to $b$? Is there something to do with projection?

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/alternate-bases/orthogonal-projections/v/linear-algebra-least-squares-approximation This is a good video for visualizing projection in least square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, exactly. $x$ is the solution of the Gauss Normal Equation, which is equivalent to the statements that $x$ is a minimiser of  $f(x')=||Ax' - b||$ and $Ax=Pb$, where $P$ is the orthogonal projection from $\mathbb{R}^3$  to $R(A)$ (the image of $A$).